# How do I add a "catch all" block to my nginx config?

Tags: nginx

I want to add a "catch all" block that returns 444 if anyone tries to hit my IP address with no host header. Right now if anyone hits my IP, it returns one specific random site that I am hosting. (same one every time)

I tried creating a /etc/nginx/sites-available/null.conf with the following contents:

```
server {
  listen                *:80;
  server_name           "";
  access_log            off;
  error_log             /dev/null emerg;
  location / {
    return 444;
  }
}
```

As described here:
https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx/issues/261#issuecomment-67095371
and of course I created the symlink and restarted nginx, but no luck, it still returns that one certain site.

Not sure what to try now.

OS is Debian 8.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
listen 80 default_server;
```

The `default_server` makes this virtualhost the default to serve if no matching virtual host is found.